# DRF: How do you create multiple "detail" views for a model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a django model that has *multiple* fields that need to be used as a key, and also has some detail views.

For example, my endpoints currently look like this, using `detail=True` to get the second set:

```
my.api/things/{id_1} (GET, POST, DELETE)
my.api/things/{id_1}/whatever (GET, POST)
```

That's all great, but I have to get to something that looks like this instead:

```
my.api/things/{id_1} (GET, POST, DELETE)
my.api/things/{id_1}/whatever (GET, POST)

my.api/things/other_id/{id_2} (GET, POST, DELETE)
my.api/things/other_id/{id_2}/whatever (GET, POST)
```

If it helps, the set of detail endpoints (ie. `whatever`) is identical, and there's no difference in *functionality* between the two. I just need to be able to access the database through either field.

I'm new to django so I'm sorry if this is a simple question. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: can you please explain in detail, sorry but I'm not able to understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply inherit base class and make whatever you want.

For example,

```
class MultipleFieldLookupMixin:
    """
    Apply this mixin to any view or viewset to get multiple field filtering
    based on a `lookup_fields` attribute, instead of the default single field filtering.
    """
    def get_object(self):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()             # Get the base queryset
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(queryset)  # Apply any filter backends
        filter = {}
        for field in self.lookup_fields:
            if self.kwargs[field]: # Ignore empty fields.
                filter[field] = self.kwargs[field]
        obj = get_object_or_404(queryset, **filter)  # Lookup the object
        self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)
        return obj
```

You can then simply apply this mixin to a view or viewset anytime you need to apply the custom behavior.

```
class RetrieveUserView(MultipleFieldLookupMixin, generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    lookup_fields = ['account', 'username']
```